# 2 dc-dc converters in series?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, series, output

[image]

I have 2 of theses converters. I am trying to get 48v. Can I connect the outputs in series to achieve this?

Comment: Depends on if the output is floating relative to the input or not. Set your multimeter to beep/continuity/ohm mode and measure input to output. What do you get? Especially black to black.

Comment: frank - Hi, Can you please [Edit] your question to include a link to the datasheet of that device? Or did it come from Amazon / AliExpress etc. with no datasheet? :-(

Comment: In these types of converters, the grounds are almost always common.  This means the answer is no.  You can check and see if there is continuity between the two black wires.

Answer (score 3):

The two black wires indicate to me that the input '-' and output '-' are, most likely, internally connected.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fddLas.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. If the inputs and outputs share a common then parallel connection of the inputs and series connection of the outputs will short-circuit U2.*

Answer (score 0):

> Can I connect the outputs in series to achieve this?

No, you cannot.

IF it does not say Isolated Converter, it is NOT and it does not so cascading the outputs would short the 1st one. V- to V+

Stepping up voltage also steps up input current demand so 10A out at 48V would demand more about 45A @ 12V and drain a fully charged car battery in less an hour at full load.